# Write a simple proxy server with python, just strange chars in browser

Tags: python, http, proxy, urllib2, basehttpserver

Im trying to write a simple Http proxy with python.
This is my code:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import urllib2
import threading
HOST_NAME="localhost"
PORT_NUMBER=9090

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def handle_get_async(self):
        opener =  urllib2.build_opener()
        #opener.addheaders = self.headers.items()
        response = opener.open(self.path)
        response_content=response.read()
        response.close()
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type",response.info().type)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response_content)

    def handle_head_async(s):
        s.send_responde(200)
        s.send_Header("Content-type","text/html")
        s.end_headers()

    def do_HEAD(s):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_head_async)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()

    def do_GET(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_get_async)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), RequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

So everything works fine, but when I use opener.addheaders = self.headers.items() to copy the headers send by the browser and copy it to the new request I just recive just strange characters in the browser like this:

> Ô½Yo#I¶&ø^¿ÂÓ«:¯”)JÜ—PJn’(q’ZCQ^Nw#ÝEßä)**€z`€æi€™—‹žy¨Ûfè—Æ4ptþ‰ê·ÂEãöüŒ9ÇÌÝé\œŠHeõB$Ý–sŽ}fvì˜Ùq³Ÿ¾«uªƒÛnS];þÍOøÅi¢1>âeÂsª|ÄD‰MsÂs’&:Îo˜ÂƒÃcb"ÊÇ?éÄ9Im‡¸G¼çŽEž;8þÉ‘lÕrGž!¹ªipÄ˜žhž£ìˆ»ÃÀáŽO¦½3mNæTƒw¥÷ò‡#>?©£™jÈælß&žj“¦ø<ßý¸¶óþïêÆôï>ì w?Í!áñÈO?ÿøÇŸ‡;ðâ?…¢|äÅñÉR-"¸æ„ü¾|óðÔÌ‰:ñHEÎ[c~×G˜»ò»³®Ñq34aAÉ?8 °õ?8‰äHö~?vÙ$v"9–~O<{”Èø?S‡Ä

Has someone an idea whats the problem?